# how to sketch a distribution function and calculate F(Y)

Tags: probability

Given these values how do you sketch this distribution function? This is about continous probability.

P(y): .4, .3, .2, .1

y :    1,  2,  3,  4

How work I be able to calculate F(y) and draw it.

Comment: You draw the graph of $F(y)$ first and then differentiate to compute $f(y) = F'(y)$ and draw its graph as well.

Comment: It looks discrete to me.

Comment: @AndréNicolas hm... so what I did for F(y) was:

0 for y <1, 

0.4 for 1<=y<2, 

0.7 for 2<=y<3, 

0.9 for 3<=y<4, 

and 1 for y>4

is this correct?

Comment: On the assumption that your $P(y)$ are the probability that $Y=y$, recall that $F_Y(y)$ is the probability that $Y\le y$. It is defined for **all real** values of $y$. For $y\lt 1$, we have $F_Y(y)=0$. Then at $y=1$, $F_Y(y)$ **jumps** to $0.4$. It stays there for $1\le y\lt 2$. Then at $2$ it **jumps** to $0.7$. Stays there, but at $3$ jumps to $0.9$, then at $4$ jumps to $1$ and stays there. So flat line, then jump to flat line, then $\dots$.

Comment: I typed while your last comment was being completed. Your solution is right.